# Sum-product in R for specific conditions

Tags: r, excel

I'm looking to do `sumproduct` in [r](/questions/tagged/r) as we do in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).
It's a little challenging as i have to apply some logical conditions meanwhile.

Excel code looks like this

```
 SUMPRODUCT(--(ID=A2),--(INDIRECT(A1)<>"-"),INDIRECT(B1),C1)
```

here ID, A1 ,B1 are name ranges on other sheet of same workbook.

```
ID  $   Quantity
1   23  34
2   4   55
3   NA  6
4   6   45
5   7   NA
6   8   NA
```

I want logical operators because some values are `NA` and I don't want to take them in consideration. I want this process to be automated without much manual work.

I've done this upto some extent using dplyr but it's not giving satisfactory results.

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: Please give a reproducible example for your R dataframe. Perhaps you could post the results of `dput(head(df))` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: In any event, you are probably looking at something along the lines of `sum(x*y, na.rm = TRUE)`